# Eigenvalue changes in sign when performed row operations.

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Eigenvalue of triangular matrix are elements in diagonal.

Now, consider the following matrix with eigenvalue $-5$ and $4$:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
       -4 & 2 \\
        4 & 3 \\
        \end{bmatrix}$$
Now if I do row operation $R_2\to R_2-(-R_1)$ and convert above matrix to following
$$\begin{bmatrix}
       -4 & 2 \\
        0 & 5 \\
        \end{bmatrix}$$
The eigenvalue of this is $-4$, $5$

First one is correct, what is wrong with the second one?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2160552/elementary-row-operation-change-the-eigenvalue-of-a-matrix

Comment: Why do you think that elementary row operations preserve eigenvalues?